# Contacts delete and re-add to mobilePush?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sdk

We have implemented a contact deletion process.
This was done to save extra license costs.

So the same contacts who have been deleted may be resynced from SFCRM after some time, depending on the relevant campaigns.

We understand the meaning, and loss of all history and data, and are ok with that.

But, I'm wondering how will this affect the push contacts.

We have implemented the SDK in our App, so a contact is subscribed in MC once he downloads and logs in to the App.

I assume that if he is deleted from MC, and then synced again, we will not be able to send him any push notifications? as all of the Fierbase/ios data is lost?

And if so, is the only way to subscribe him again will be to ask him to remove and install the App again?

Will appreciate advice on that.